# C# WPF delete checked items in treeview

Tags: c#, wpf

If i have a treeview like this:

Book
   -->items
CD
   -->items

and every item contains a checkbox, how can i remove all the selected checkboxes.

Note: i don't use treenode.

I have a treeview with 3 treeview items(i.e book,cd and dvd). Dynamically i create nodes:

```
TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem();

 newChild.Header = cbox;
```

if for example 5 treeviewitems are checked(for remove) then i want to remove them.

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForm ? If not TreeNode, then what are you using. Please elaborate. We're not psychic (yet).

Comment: If you don't use a treenode, how are you adding objects to the treeview? This question doesn't make a lot of sense; please edit to add more information.

Comment: So, you actually just want an algorithm to run a tree and delete nodes?

Comment: yes that the nodes that are checked, there is a checkbox before each item

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
void DeleteSelectedItems(TreeView root)
{
    var todelete = List<TreeViewItem>();
    GetSelectedItems(root.Items, todelete);
    foreach(var it in todelete)
    {
        var parent = it.Parent;
        parent.Items.Remove(it);
    }
}

void GetSelectedItems(ItemsCollection tree, List<TreeViewItem> todelete)
{
    foreach(var it in tree)
    {
        if (((it as TreeViewItem).Header as CheckBox).Checked)
            todelete.Add(it);
        else
            GetSelectedItems(it.Items, todelete);
    }
}
```