# WPF Treeviewitem

Tags: c#, wpf

Suggest i have this treeview:

```
 <TreeView Height="295" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,58,0,0" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Boek" Name="BoekenLijst" Width="260" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="CD" Name="CDLijst" Width="260" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="DVD" Name="DVDLijst" Width="260" />
        </TreeView>
```

In the 3 Treeviewitems I dynamically put treeviewitems in with checkboxes on it.

I am trying to remove the selected items, at the moment i did this:

```
TreeViewItem parent = treeView1.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
     //What do i need to put here so i can remove the selected childs?
```

Comment: You asked the same question two hours ago...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WPF delete checked items in treeview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661208/c-wpf-delete-checked-items-in-treeview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the selected item directly, try:

```
treeView1.Items.Remove(treeView1.SelectedItem);
```

If you want to delete all sub items of the selected item:

```
ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> helper = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>();
foreach(TreeViewItem item in treeView1.SelectedItem.Items)
{
  helper.Add(item);
}

foreach(TreeViewItem item in helper)
{
  treeView1.SelectedItem.Items.Remove(item);
}
```